# Can someone help me with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct COMPLEX{
    int x; 
    int y;
};

void add(struct COMPLEX *b[]);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    struct COMPLEX a[3];
    struct COMPLEX *ptr[] = { &a[0] , &a[1] , &a[2] };

    printf("Indtast a->x = ");
    scanf("%d", a[0].x);
    printf("Indtast a->y = ");
    scanf("%d", a[0].y);
    printf("Indtast a2->x = ");
    scanf("%d", a[1].x);
    printf("Indtast a2->y = ");
    scanf("%d", a[1].y);
    printf("Indtast a3->x = ");
    scanf("%d", a[2].x);
    printf("Indtast a3->y = ");
    scanf("%d", a[2].y);

    add(ptr);

    return 0;
}

void add(struct COMPLEX *b[]){

    printf("%d + i%d",b[0].x + b[1].x + b[2].x, b[0].y + b[1].y + b[2].y);

}
```

Im trying to point this array of my structure til the function, that will print the calculated complex number. But it gives me an error.
Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `scanf("%d", a[0].x);` --> `scanf("%d", &a[0].x);`

Comment: For future reference "But it gives me an error" --> better to post the error message than only announce an error was received.

Comment: What's the pointer array good for? Seems it is just creating a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to add "&" operator in scanf

try this

```
 struct COMPLEX{
 int x; 
 int y;
 };

 void add(struct COMPLEX *b[]);

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

 struct COMPLEX a[3];
 struct COMPLEX *ptr[] = { &a[0] , &a[1] , &a[2] };

 printf("Indtast a->x = ");
 scanf("%d", &a[0].x);
 printf("Indtast a->y = ");
 scanf("%d", &a[0].y);
 printf("Indtast a2->x = ");
 scanf("%d", &a[1].x);
 printf("Indtast a2->y = ");
 scanf("%d", &a[1].y);
 printf("Indtast a3->x = ");
 scanf("%d", &a[2].x);
 printf("Indtast a3->y = ");
 scanf("%d", &a[2].y);

 add(ptr);

 return 0;
 }

 void add(struct COMPLEX *b[]){

 printf("%d + i%d",b[0].x + b[1].x + b[2].x, b[0].y + b[1].y + b[2].y);

 }
```

Comment: Perfect, it works now, but i had to set arrow in the function to, like b[0]->x.
Thank you very much!

Comment: select my reply as answer

Answer (score 0):

> scanf() stands for scan formatted string. Now while scanning input
>   from standard input stream, scanf() needs to put that input data into
>   somewhere. To store the formatted input data, scanf() needs to know
>   the memory location of a variable of same data type.
>   & Indicates the memory location of variable.

correction in your code put & where you are reading input from somewhere in your code like:-

```
scanf("%d", &a[0].x);
```